# How to run npm install and run gulp with ANT

Tags: xml, ant, gulp

I'm trying to run npm install and run gulp after the `npm install` with ANT `build.xml` file... when i run ant the the ant command is executing without any error, but nor `npm install` or `gulp` is not executed...

Here is what i have done in build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="gulp">
    <npminstall>npm install</npminstall>
    <target name="gulp">
        <gulp file="dist/op/generator/gulpfile.js"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Ant doesn't natively have an `npminstall` task or a `gulp` task. It looks like you're trying to run custom tasks from a 3rd party library named ant4x. See http://ant4x.sourceforge.net/tasks/javascript/npm/ and http://ant4x.sourceforge.net/tasks/javascript/gulp/

Answer (score 0):

Just like you do it in the terminal you can do this using exec task https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html